# Magnetic Field in a Leaky Capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, capacitance

Consider a spherical capacitor which is made of two concentric spherical shells. The capacitor is charged so that outer shell carries a positive charge and the inner shell carries a negative charge of the same magnitude. Eventually the charges leak due to small electrical conductivity between the shells. Will the magnetic field be produced due to the leakage current?

I think that there should not be a magnetic field. I used poynting vector for this. The electric field and the energy density both change radially. Is it a correct solution? If not, what is the correct explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean to say that flow of energy can only be radially outwards due to symmetry, and since $\vec E$ already points in that direction, you can't have $\vec S$ pointing in that direction, so $\vec S$ must be $0$, and hence $\vec B$ must be parallel to $\vec E$, but this violates divergenceless-ness of $\vec B$, then I think your method is correct.

Here is an alternate method:

Let the charge on the inner conductor be $Q(t)$
The current density at a distance $r$ from the centre is $$\vec j = -4\pi r^2\frac{dQ}{dt} \hat r$$

The electric field there is $\vec E = \frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2} \hat r$, so $$\frac{d\vec E}{dt} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\frac{dQ}{dt} \hat r$$

Now, we have $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ and also $\nabla\times\vec B = \mu_0 \vec j + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{d\vec E}{dt} = 0$ (this is valid outside the outer surface as well since $\frac{d\vec{E}}{dt}$ and $\vec{j}$ are $0$ there anyways). Using the boundary condition that $\vec{B}$ goes to $0$ as $r$ goes to infinity, we get $\vec B = 0$